# How to explain and usage of "array in struct"?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct A
{
     short B;
     short C;
} New_Type;

struct Move_Information
{
     New_Type Position [25];
};
```

I am a newbie in C, and I don't really understand the meaning of "array in struct".

Could any wizard explain how to use it ? Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, what's so strange about it? It's just an array that is a member of a struct, what is unclear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you had a plain old c type in a struct:

```
struct Other_Information
{
    int x[25];
};
```

You could then make one of these structs and access the data member as follows:

```
Other_Information info;
info.x[0] = 42;//set the first item
```

Similarly, for Move_Information you can index into the array, then access that structures members a so:

```
Move_Information info;
info.Position[0].B = 42;
```

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that one member in a struct, `Position` in your case, is an array. In this case it's an array of the type `New_Type`, which happens to be a `struct` too, but that doesn't matter.

You can access indexed elements of the array just as with any other array:

```
struct Move_Information moves;
moves.Position[0].B = 12;
moves.Position[0].C = 4711;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing but declaring a structure which contains array of type New_type .

to use it  -

Struct Move_Information new_node ;

```
new_node.position[x].B =  "your B data ";
new_node.position[x].C =  "your C data ";
```

Hope it clarifies your doubt .

Comment: semi-colons are for wimps?